# Delphi set Assignable Constants True for Command Line Build

Tags: delphi, command-prompt

When building my project with RAD Studio Command Prompt, I get the following Error: 
error E2064: Left side cannot be assigned to

I know that this has to do with the Assignable Typed Constants issue and I know where to turn it of in the Embaracadero compiler, however I need to set this settings outside the compiler.

My config file currently looks like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
    <DCC_HppOutput>c:\d64\DCUfiles</DCC_HppOutput>
    <DCC_ObjOutput>c:\d64\DCUfiles</DCC_ObjOutput>
    <DCC_UnitSearchPath>c:\d64\sf\cis;C:\d64\Dcu64;C:\d64\ProkonRibbon;$(DCC_UnitSearchPath)</DCC_UnitSearchPath>
    <Icon_MainIcon>Frame_Icon.ico</Icon_MainIcon>
    <DCC_LocalDebugSymbols>true</DCC_LocalDebugSymbols>
    <VerInfo_Release>67</VerInfo_Release>
    <DCC_ImportedDataReferences>false</DCC_ImportedDataReferences>
    <DCC_StrictVarStrings>false</DCC_StrictVarStrings>
    <DCC_Define>_VER7;_VER7;_VER7;_VER7;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
    <DCC_DcuOutput>c:\d64\Dcu64</DCC_DcuOutput>
    <DCC_ExeOutput>c:\prokon\bin64</DCC_ExeOutput>
    <VerInfo_Keys>CompanyName=;
                FileDescription=;
                FileVersion=2.6.67.0;
                InternalName=;
                LegalCopyright=;
                LegalTrademarks=;
                OriginalFilename=;
                ProductName=;
                ProductVersion=2.6.67.0;
                Comments=23 Jul 2015
    </VerInfo_Keys>
    <VerInfo_Locale>1033</VerInfo_Locale>
    <VerInfo_MinorVer>6</VerInfo_MinorVer>
</PropertyGroup>
<ProjectExtensions>
    <Borland.Personality>Delphi.Personality.12</Borland.Personality>
    <Borland.ProjectType>OptionSet</Borland.ProjectType>
    <BorlandProject>
        <Delphi.Personality/>
    </BorlandProject>
    <ProjectFileVersion>12</ProjectFileVersion>
</ProjectExtensions>
```

Is there a way to set the Assignable Typed Constants property in this file?

Comment: This feature is intended not to be used. You need to be disabling it rather than enabling it.

Answer (score 4):

Add inside `<PropertyGroup>` tag

```
<DCC_WriteableConstants>true</DCC_WriteableConstants>
```

You can also include that setting in source code with `{$J+}` or `{$WRITEABLECONST ON}` compiler switch. That would be most preferable option, since code cannot be compiled without it.

Another benefit of using compiler directive in code is that you can selectively apply writeable typed constants instead of making all typed constants writeable.

```
const
  {$WRITEABLECONST ON}
  x: integer = 1;
  {$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
  y: integer = 2;

begin
  writeln(x); // -> 1
  x := 3;
  writeln(x); // -> 3
  y := 4; // does not compile
end.
```

Comment: It would be the **second** most preferable option, the most preferable being changing the code so that `WRITEABLECONST` isn't needed (as David already pointed out). :-)

Comment: @UliGerhardt Unless I see evidence that someone is going to shoot himself in the foot using some feature, I prefer just answering the question asked :)

Comment: OK, nitpicker's corner. OP asked how to set the option in the *.dproj. Your answer goes into the *.pas. :-P

Comment: @UliGerhardt True, but my advice is relevant in his case. Since code cannot be compiled without having assignable typed constants turned on, the best place to put instructions to compiler is the source code itself. It alleviates the need to edit and rely on specifics in .dproj file that are sometimes seen as transient files and can be either deleted by devs or messed up by the IDE.

Comment: I have to admit that I have one or two `{$WRITEABLECONST ON}` in my code, too, to simulate a C static variable at function scope.

Comment: A global variable, or a class var, can do the job just fine. I see no need for writeable typed constant. Asker is almost certainly shooting themselves in the foot. I frankly have no truck with a language feature that names variables as constants.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan First, I am not going to take sides for or against writable typed constants. But theoretically speaking you can much more easily shoot yourself in the foot using global var you forget to assign than using assignable typed constant that has to be initialized to some value in the first place.

Comment: Global variables are initialized. That's not the issue. The issue is turning all your typed constants into variables.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Global vars are initialized but not necessarily to desired value. You have a point with turning all typed constants to variables and that is another reason for using compiler switch in source code, only around constants you want to be writable.

Comment: @Dalija Here's a typed constant: `const MyRecord: TMyRecord = ();` So they may be default initialized too. I'm surprised when I hear anyone arguing in favour of variable constants, an oxymoron of epic proportions. This isn't even a feature that was intended to exist. It was an accident. Because early versions of TP ran on systems without protected memory.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It is oxymoron only because you are looking at it as constant. If you look at it as variable initialized to some value then it is not something out of the ordinary. "Problem" is that Delphi does not have initializable variables but has writeable constants.

Comment: It's a huge problem when the language is controlled by options. You can have one or the other, but not both.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You can have both. See example in my answer.

Comment: You can't have both. The option is either on or off.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't follow. In Delphi if you want to initialize variable at place of declaration you can use writeable typed constant. Never mind that it is called constant, that part is more about syntax than semantic. And if you use compiler directive only around that constant, then other typed constants will not be affected. And if you don't need your typed constant to act as variable, then you just leave it as is, no compiler switches needed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I would prefer using `var x: integer = 2; ... x := 5;` but you cannot do that in Delphi. So if you want to do above you have to write `{$J+} const x: integer = 2; {$J-} ... x := 5;` I don't see anything wrong with that. It is just matter of what syntax you have to use to achieve xyz functionality.

Comment: It's an accidental feature that only appeared due to implementation detail accidents. It's pretty unusable due to the conditionals. I'm amazed that you thing it is a good feature. It is absolutely not comparable with local variables. The scope is local but the storage is global. It's a global variable, something we already have. As a hard and fast rule, anytime a language keyword has meaning controlled by a compiler option, it is a misfeature.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have already said that I am not for nor against writeable typed constants, I am just trying to be as objective as I can.

Comment: I'm being objective. It's a misfeature. The code in you answer appals me. It is accurate but it should come with a health warning. To tell the asker that writeable typed constants are fine to use is very bad in my view.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There are some bad features that have to be used with caution, `with` comes to mind. Writeable typed constants do not fall into that category. The worst thing that could happen is that some day they may be removed from the language, and possibly replaced with proper `var` declaration. Without code to be seen (that may be misusing them) I do not want to judge their usage. You are blowing this out of proportion.

Comment: So it's fine in your view to do what the akser intends to do. I disagree vehemently.

Comment: The <DCC_WriteableConstant> tag did the job - thank you.  Unfortunately I am not allowed to alter the base classes of the code that I am using so no Compiler Directives or altering of the variables.

Comment: Even if second part of the answer is not usable for your particular case, you can still accept the answer because first part answers your question. And future readers also might find second part valuable, so I will leave it there.